# Change Dojo contentpane attribute using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dojo, contentpane

I have a Dojo (1.8) [contentpane](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dijit/layout/ContentPane.html):

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="splitter:false, region:'leading', href:'page2.php?name=variableName'" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" id="embeddedPg"> <!-- Embedded content shown here --> </div>
```

I am trying to change the value of the `href` attribute of the `data-dojo-props`. I wrote a JavaScript function as follows:

```
function loadInfo(tableName){           
        var dojowidget = document.getElementById("embeddedPg");
        dojowidget.setAttribute("data-dojo-props","href:page2.php?name="+tableName);
    }
```

This function is called when the user clicks on a particular link on the page, and is getting called appropriately.
It does not give me any JavaScript error, but it does not work either. What would be the correct way to do this? I am using Dojo 1.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementById` doesn't return dojo widget. It just returns DOM object.

To access dojo widget, you should use `dijit/registry.byId`.
You can change href attribute via `ContentPane's attr(name,value)` and you should call `refresh()` to display it.

```
require(["dijit/layout/ContentPane", "dijit/registry",  "dojo/domReady!"]
  ,function(ContentPane, registry) {

    var refreshPage = function(tableName) {
        var cPane = registry.byId("embeddedPg");
        cPane.attr("href", "page2.php?name="+tableName);
        cPane.refresh();
    }
});
```